# docker-compose command not bringing up all containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a compose file that has a number of services that use an image, and then 4-5 that use a `build` command.  The command `docker-compose up -d --no-recreate service-a` brings up all the services using an image, and then only `service-a` of the ones using `build` instructions.

I can't find any documentation on what exactly is happening here, I can only guess that the `docker-compose up -d` picks up the services using an image, and then `--no-recreate` prevents any of the images being built, but anything you specify after that has already been built will also be brought up?  I'd like to understand this behavior.

Comment: Show your docker-compose.yml. Please create an [MCVE]

Comment: Something like this could be possible if `service-a/Dockerfile` tries to `RUN` its server process rather than making it be its `CMD`, so the first build never completes.